# Rotate component labels in Circuitkz

Tags: circuitikz

There are cases, especially with variable components like vC and vL that look weird when turned. At the same time you might want the label to be on the other side, because there is some component in the way.

`rotate=180` and similar commands don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look into the manual reveals that it possible to archive this with

```
(0,0) to [vC, l=$C_L$] (2,0)
(0,2) to [vC, l=$C_L$, mirror] (2,2)
(3,0) to [vC, l_=$C_L$] (5,0)
(3,2) to [vC, l_=$C_L$, mirror] (5,2)
```

which produces

[image]

note that `l=$C_L$` equals `l^=$C_L$`.